# AWS generating CloudFormation from Lambda S3 Use Case

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a bunch of Lambdas, SQSs and S3 sources/destinations as DataLake which I want to convert to a template/CloudFormation stack.

How do i do this? Is there any way to automatically generate this or i might have to do it manually learning YAML CloudFormation templates?

[image: AWS Use Case]

Thank you!

Comment: You can [Bring existing resources into CloudFormation management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) but this app looks reasonably simple so it may be worthwhile just deciding on your serverless deployment tooling first (e.g. SAM, serverless framework, CDK, Chalice) and then creating the app from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool called [Former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) you could try to use. The issue you will have with CloudFormation is existing, manually created resources can't usually be managed by it without [importing and that only works for certain resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html).

If you are looking for a tool to assist with creating the resources from the ground up and are already doing development in a supported language you could take a look at [CDK (Cloud Development Kit)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html), which makes working with CloudFormation a bit easier.